# OpenSSL не видит ГОСТ алгоритм

Tags: openssl

Всем еще раз добрый день, я все еще страдаю от OpenSSL, теперь другая проблема, мне нужно выпустить ключ с шифрованием через ГОСТ по алгоритму gost2001.
Все требования вроде учтены, но он не видит этот алгоритм, вот так выглядит файл openssl.cnf

```
openssl_conf=openssl_def
HOME                     = .
RANDFILE                 = $ENV::HOME/.rnd
oid_section              = new_oids
[ new_oids ]
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7
[ ca ]
default_ca       = CA_default
[ CA_default ]
dir = ./demoCA
certs            = $dir/certs
crl_dir          = $dir/crl
database         = $dir/index.txt

new_certs_dir    = $dir/newcerts
certificate      = $dir/cacert.pem
serial           = $dir/serial
crlnumber        = $dir/crlnumber

crl             = $dir/crl.pem
private_key     = $dir/private/cakey.pem
RANDFILE        = $dir/private/.rand
x509_extensions = usr_cert
name_opt        = ca_default
cert_opt        = ca_default
default_days    = 365
default_crl_days= 30
default_md      = default
preserve        = no
policy          = policy_match
[ policy_match ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional
[ policy_anything ]
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional
[ req ]
default_bits            = 2048
default_keyfile         = privkey.pem
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
attributes              = req_attributes
req_extensions = v3_req
x509_extensions = v3_ca
string_mask = utf8only
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default             = RU
countryName_min                 = 2
countryName_max                 = 2
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default     = Moscow region
localityName                    = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default            = Moscow
0.organizationName              = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default      = JSC Example
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default  = It Department
commonName                      = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max                  = 64
emailAddress                    = Email Address
emailAddress_max                = 64
[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword               = A challenge password
challengePassword_min           = 4
challengePassword_max           = 20
unstructuredName                = An optional company name
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = test.example.ru
DNS.2 = gost.example.ru

[ usr_cert ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
nsComment                       = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = CA:true
[ crl_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always
[ proxy_cert_ext ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
nsComment                       = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo
[ tsa ]
default_tsa = tsa_config1
[ tsa_config1 ]
dir             = ./demoCA
serial          = $dir/tsaserial
crypto_device   = builtin
signer_cert     = $dir/tsacert.pem

certs           = $dir/cacert.pem

signer_key      = $dir/private/tsakey.pem
default_policy  = tsa_policy1

other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3
digests         = md5, sha1
accuracy        = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100
clock_precision_digits  = 0
ordering                = yes
tsa_name                = yes

ess_cert_id_chain       = no

[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section
[engine_section]
gost = gost_section
[gost_section]
engine_id = gost
dynamic_path = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1/gost.so
default_algorithms = ALL
CRYPT_PARAMS = id-Gost28147-89-CryptoPro-A-ParamSet
```

а вот вывод команды по созданию

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm gost2001 -pkeyopt paramset:A -out gost.secrettic.ru.key
Algorithm gost2001 not found
```

Связку использую
Nginx 1.21.0
Openssl 1-1.0.2h

Answer (score 0):

В `openssl` мейнстриме нет поддержки шифров ГОСТ. Чтобы убедиться, выполните команду `openssl ciphers|tr ':' '\n'|grep GOST`. Во всех нерусских дистрибутивах эта команда должна вернуть пустую строку.

Вам нужна специальная сборка `openssl` из отечественных дистрибутивов. Например, openssl из AltLinux: https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-x86_64/13/

Либо можете сами собрать реализацию гостовых шифров https://github.com/gost-engine/engine (ветка для openssl-1.0.2 https://github.com/gost-engine/engine/tree/openssl_1_0_2)